# Angular: format date and skip timezones

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, timezone, dayjs

How can I format date-time in Angular with `DatePipe.format()` & skip all timezone conversion regardless where I am.
For example for such examples all over the world (regardless time) I want to get `07/06/2022`:

```
console.log('2022-07-06T00:00:00.000Z :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T00:00:00.000Z', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T06:00:00.000Z :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T06:00:00.000Z', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T13:00:00.000Z : ', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T13:00:00.000Z', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T23:59:59.000Z :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T23:59:59.000Z', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');

console.log('2022-07-06T00:00:00-07:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T00:00:00-07:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T06:00:00-07:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T06:00:00-07:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T13:00:00-07:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T13:00:00-07:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T23:59:59-07:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T23:59:59-07:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');

console.log('2022-07-06T00:00:00-12:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T00:00:00-12:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T06:00:00-12:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T06:00:00-12:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T13:00:00-12:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T13:00:00-12:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T23:59:59-12:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T23:59:59-12:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');

console.log('2022-07-06T00:00:00+12:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T00:00:00+12:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T06:00:00+12:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T06:00:00+12:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T13:00:00+12:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T13:00:00+12:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T23:59:59+12:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T23:59:59+12:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');

console.log('2022-07-06T00:00:00+07:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T00:00:00+07:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T06:00:00+07:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T06:00:00+07:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T13:00:00+07:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T13:00:00+07:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T23:59:59+07:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T23:59:59+07:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');

console.log('2022-07-06T00:00:00+00:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T00:00:00+00:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T06:00:00+00:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T06:00:00+00:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T13:00:00+00:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T13:00:00+00:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
console.log('2022-07-06T23:59:59+00:00 :', this.datePipe.transform('2022-07-06T23:59:59+00:00', 'MM/dd/yyyy', '+0000'), '\n\n');
```

all this examples should return `07/06/2022`.
I tried different approaches - but still can see issues.

The only way I found is a very dirty solution:

```
if (date?.match(/^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/)) {
  return date.substring(5, 7) + '/' + value.substring(8, 10) + '/' + value.substring(0, 4);
}
```

Basically take string and parse values from it. I don't think it's a pretty way.
Also I'm using `dayjs` and tried: `dayjs(date).tz('Greenwich').format('MM/DD/YYYY');`

How can I get the same date everywhere?

Comment: Looks like you use dayjs, did you try `dayjs(‘date’).format(MM/DD/YYYY’)`?

Comment: @Rana_S it would be different in different zones. Yes, I tried.

Comment: @Rana_S for example `2022-07-06T00:00:00+12:00` in +12 / 0 / -12 would be different... should be 07/06/2022

Comment: After 2h of research, my conclusion is that the issue is most likely related to daylight savings time + CET format, If I was in your shoes I would go for creating a pipe, that will be slicing the first n elements, split them by `-` and build the desired string after that.

Comment: Why do you think it's a "dirty solution"? Any conversion of string to a Date (or even just reformatting) requires parsing, whether done by you, a library or built–in function. So if your solution is "dirty", then so are all solutions as they all rely on parsing. A much simper parse and format is: `let [y, m, d] = s.split(/\D/);
console.log(\`${m}/${d}/${y}\`);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your inputs are strings in ISO 8601 date+time+offset format as you showed, then you can define a function to extract the offset from the string:

```
const getOffset = (s) => s.match(/[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}$|Z$/)[0];
```

This will (for example) return `-07:00`, `+12:00` or `Z` from your input strings, which happen to be exactly the format that Angular's date pipe uses for its `timeZone` parameter.

```
const input = '2022-07-06T00:00:00-07:00';
const output = this.datePipe.transform(input, 'shortDate', getOffset(input));
```

*Note that I used `shortDate` here to avoid localization issues.  I recommend you do the same.*

Alternatively, you could use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon), which has this built in:

```
DateTime.fromISO(yourInputString, { setZone: true }).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_SHORT)
```

The [`setZone`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/zones?id=setzone) option will automatically set time zone offset from the value in the string.  Then, when you call [`toLocaleString`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=tolocalestring-strings-for-humans) (or any of the other many formatting functions provided by Luxon), the results will reflect the original input, without any time zone conversion.

Also, you asked about using day.js for this.  You can do so, but you would need to add logic to support keeping the zone when you parsed it, as that functionality is not built-in to day.js.  [See this issue](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/651).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that I can add one more lib for dates... 
>  to extract the time zone offset from the end of the input string
what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, if `-07:00` is at the end of your input string, pass `-07:00` to the timezone parameter of the date pipe.  If `Z` is at the end of the input string, pass `+00:00`.  etc.

Comment: @brabertaser19 - I updated my question to include that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I tried many ways but it doesn't work, maybe just cut the string to cheat

```
const dateArr = [
      '2022-07-06T00:00:00+00:00',
      '2022-07-06T00:00:00.000Z',
      '2022-07-06T06:00:00.000Z',
      '2022-07-06T13:00:00.000Z',
      '2022-07-06T23:59:59.000Z',
      '2022-07-06T00:00:00-07:00',
      '2022-07-06T06:00:00-07:00',
      '2022-07-06T13:00:00-07:00',
      '2022-07-06T23:59:59-07:00',
      '2022-07-06T00:00:00-12:00',
      '2022-07-06T06:00:00-12:00',
      '2022-07-06T13:00:00-12:00',
      '2022-07-06T23:59:59-12:00',
      '2022-07-06T00:00:00+12:00',
      '2022-07-06T06:00:00+12:00',
      '2022-07-06T13:00:00+12:00',
      '2022-07-06T23:59:59+12:00',
      '2022-07-06T00:00:00+07:00',
      '2022-07-06T06:00:00+07:00',
      '2022-07-06T13:00:00+07:00',
      '2022-07-06T23:59:59+07:00',
      '2022-07-06T00:00:00+00:00',
      '2022-07-06T06:00:00+00:00',
      '2022-07-06T13:00:00+00:00',
      '2022-07-06T23:59:59+00:00'
    ];
    dateArr.forEach(date => {
      const result = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(date.slice(0,10)),'MM/dd/yyyy');
      console.log(result);
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can reset timezone

```js
function convertDate(input){
    return new Date(input.split('T')[0])
}

console.log(convertDate('2022-07-06T00:00:00+07:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own pipe to cut off the time, then use a `parseIso` and `format` function from `date-fns`.

```js
transform(date: string, dateFormat = 'yyyy') {
  const dateObj = parseIso(date.slice(0, 10));

  return format(dateObj, dateFormat);
}
```

We use this library extensively in our project and it helps a lot with time zoneless dates across the globe to show a unified date.

`parseIso` - take a string to work a date out from it. Compared to `new Date()` it does not create the date in the UTC timezone, but rather in the current one which makes it possible to have `parseIso('2000-01-01')` and have the December 1st 2000 in any timezone the code runs.

`format` - does the formatting.

`slice` removes the time and leave the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

To improve it even further the method's contents could be encapsulated in a separate function so that the `transform` method would return the result from that function call. This way should you need the transform run in a component you will only import a function with no need to inject the pipe (which is a bad idea BTW).

Answer (score -1):

Here is what i think:

In the component ts :
declare a variable call d='2022-07-06T00:00:00+00:00'(for example)

And in the HTML of the component :

```
<div>{{d| date:'dd/MM/YYYY'}}</div>
```

Now you should get 07/06/2022 no matter what timezone is.

Comment: no... it won't work